# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Information Security breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 31         43
Users destroyed                                 118          0
Users deleted                                     3          0
Users contacted                                  39          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           760      4,227
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              151        829
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        149      2,141
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               57      1,117
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               310      7,142
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              791      7,054
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             3          1
Tag synonyms created                              3          0
Revisions redacted                                8          0
Questions unprotected                             1          9
Questions reopened                               51          6
Questions protected                              21        103
Questions migrated                              327        111
Questions flagged⁴                               12      3,636
Questions closed                              2,519      1,348
Question flags handled⁴                       1,093      2,555
Posts unlocked                                    1         89
Posts undeleted                                  16        155
Posts locked                                     18        687
Posts deleted⁵                                1,349      4,962
Posts bumped                                      0      4,035
Escalations to the CM¹ team                       4          0
Comments undeleted                               32          0
Comments flagged                                  5      1,886
Comments deleted⁶                             6,033      3,762
Comment flags handled                         1,038        853
Bounties canceled                                 4          0
Answers flagged                                  35      3,774
Answer flags handled                          2,733      1,076
All comments on a post moved to chat             82          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://security.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/-1). Also referred to as CM, Community Managers.

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Those unicode superscript characters render terribly in this font. Why not use `<pre>` for the formatted text so that you are able to use `<sup>` for superscripts?

Comment: @forest - they render well in default Chrome and Safari

Comment: What is CM? It's used but not defined.

Comment: @Luc See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, I've edited the post to clarify.